# Gradle: Share version defined in buildSrc in pluginManagement/dependencies/

Tags: gradle, multi-module

I'm looking for factorizing all plugins/dependencies version used in my multimodule project. I tried different approach. For instance, I tried that one :

I created a buildSrc an object containing all versions exposed as constants (in ./buildSrc/main/kotlin/Versions.kt) :

```
object Versions {
    const val myApp = "1.0.12"

    const val kotlin = "1.8.20"
    const val agp = "7.1.3"
    const val compose = "1.4.0"
    const val ktor = "2.2.4"
    const val jUnit = "5.9.0"
}
```

I added plugin management in my root project as follow (in ./settings.gradle.kts) :

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        maven("https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/compose/dev")
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    plugins {
        kotlin("jvm").version(Versions.kotlin)
        kotlin("plugin.serialization").version(Versions.kotlin)
        kotlin("multiplatform").version(Versions.kotlin)
        kotlin("android").version(Versions.kotlin)
        id("com.android.tools.build").version(Versions.agp)
        id("com.android.base").version(Versions.agp)
        id("com.android.application").version(Versions.agp)
        id("com.android.library").version(Versions.agp)
        id("org.jetbrains.kotlin").version(Versions.kotlin)
        id("org.jetbrains.compose").version(Versions.compose)

        id("com.squareup.sqldelight").version(Versions.sqlDelight)
    }

}
```

It seems that can't work as I have the following error :

```
e: D:\src\project\settings.gradle.kts:12:31: Unresolved reference: Versions
e: D:\src\project\settings.gradle.kts:13:48: Unresolved reference: Versions
...

* What went wrong:
Script compilation errors:

  Line 12:         kotlin("jvm").version(Versions.kotlin)
                                         ^ Unresolved reference: Versions

  Line 13:         kotlin("plugin.serialization").version(Versions.kotlin)
                                                          ^ Unresolved reference: Versions
```

This approach seems bad, or I missed something something. Can you help to fix or give me the standard approach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach I found is [the one explained in the documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html#sub:central-declaration-of-dependencies) that I starting to be comfortable with :)

in the `settings.gradle.kts` of the root project, I added a catalog as following :

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
  versionCatalogs {
    create("libs") {
      version("ktor", "2.2.4")
      version("nd4j", "1.0.0-M2.1")
      version("kotlin", "1.8.20")

      library("kotlin-logging-jvm", "io.github.oshai:kotlin-logging-jvm:4.0.0-beta-23")
      library("logback-classic", "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.4.5")
      library("log4j-to-slf4j", "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:2.19.0")
      bundle("logging", listOf(
          "kotlin-logging-jvm",
          "logback-classic",
          "log4j-to-slf4j",
      ))

      library("ktor-serialization-gson-jvm", "io.ktor", "ktor-serialization-gson-jvm").versionRef("ktor")
      ....
      bundle("ktorServer", listOf(
          "ktor-server-content-negotiation-jvm",
          "ktor-server-core-jvm",
          "ktor-server-cors",
          "ktor-serialization-gson-jvm",
          "ktor-server-core",
          "ktor-server",
          "ktor-server-cio",
          "freemarker",
          "ktor-server-freemarker",
      ))

      library("ktor-client-cio", "io.ktor", "ktor-client-cio").versionRef("ktor")
      ...
      bundle("ktorClient", listOf(
          "ktor-client-cio",
          "ktor-server-netty",
          "ktor-client-content-negotiation",
          "ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json",
          "ktor-serialization-gson",
          "ktor-client-logging",
          "ktor-client-auth",
          "ktor-client-logging",
      ))

      library("jmimemagic", "net.sf.jmimemagic:jmimemagic:0.1.5")
    }
  }
}
```

And so in my submodule, I just have to add a bundle or single dependency like that in `build.gradle.kts`

```
dependencies {
  implementation(libs.bundles.logging)
  implementation(libs.bundles.ktorServer)
  implementation(libs.bundles.ktorClient)
  implementation(libs.jmimemagic)
}
```